# Completely continuous maps from projective tensor products into $c_0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $E$, $F$ be two Banach spaces and $E\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}_{\pi}F$ denote their projective tensor product.
For each unit norm $\xi\in E$ and $\gamma\in F$, let's define
$$
J_{\gamma}:E\to E\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}_{\pi}F 
\hspace{20mm}J_{\gamma}(x) = x\otimes\gamma \\
J_{\xi}:F\to E\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}_{\pi}F
\hspace{20mm}J_{\xi}(g)=\xi\otimes g
$$
Let $\hspace{3mm}T: E\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}_{\pi}F\to c_0\hspace{3mm}$ be a bounded linear operator. If $T$ is completely continuous, then clearly so are $\hspace{3mm}TJ_{\gamma}:E\to c_0\hspace{3mm}$ and $\hspace{3mm}TJ_{\xi}:F\to c_0\hspace{3mm}$.

> **Question:** Is $T$ completely continuous if $\hspace{2mm}TJ_{\gamma}\hspace{1mm}$ and $\hspace{2mm}TJ_{\xi}\hspace{1mm}$ are completely continuous for every unit norm $\hspace{2mm}\xi\in E\hspace{2mm}$ and $\hspace{2mm}\gamma\in F\hspace{2mm}$?

Comment: If I understand the question, the answer is "yes" for reflexive $E$ and $F$. This is just because if every operator from a reflexive space to $c_0$ is compact, then the reflexive space is finite dimensional and the images of your $i_\eta$ maps are norm one complemented in the tensor product.

Comment: @BillJohnson Professor Johnson, I couldn't establish the link between reflexivity and the positive answer. Could you please open it up for an amateur(=me) ? The first part of your second sentence reminded me of a restatement of Josefson-Nissenzweig theorem, although it encompasses (not only reflexive but) all Banach spaces.

Comment: It is enough to consider a separable infinite dimensional reflexive space $X$ because every non separable reflexive space has an infinite dimensional separable quotient. Every separable space has a biorthogonal sequence $(x_n,x_n^*)$ with the functionals having norm one and the vectors bounded and having dense span. $x\mapsto\langle x_n^*,x \rangle$ defines a non compact operator from $X$ into $c_0$.

Comment: @BillJohnson Sir, how would you tie this fact in with the projective tensor $E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*$ and $T:E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*\to c_0$ ? I apologize for asking too many details.